# Open Layers Cannot read property 'add Layer' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-maps, openlayers

I am trying to add a new marker to the map upon click and attempting to save title and description to display on marker hover however I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'add Layer' of undefined
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    function init() {
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
        var proj4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326");
        var projmerc = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");
        var layerOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Street Map");
        map.addLayers([layerOSM]);
        if (!map.getCenter()) map.zoomToMaxExtent();
        map.events.register("mousemove", map, function (e) {
            var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
            OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coords").innerHTML = 'MOUSE POSITION ' + position;
            var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(this.events.getMousePosition(e));
            //OpenLayers.Util.getElement("lonlatTG").innerHTML = 'lonlat => ' + lonlat;
            var lonlatTransf = lonlat.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), proj4326);
            //OpenLayers.Util.getElement("lonlatTrans").innerHTML = 'lonlatTransf => ' + lonlatTransf;
            //OpenLayers.Util.getElement("lonlatDouble").innerHTML = 'lonlat => ' + lonlat;
            document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML = "Longitude: " + lonlatTransf.lon;
            document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = "Latidue : " + lonlatTransf.lat;
        });

        map.events.register("click", map, function (e) {


            var iconT = "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-pushpin.png"; //document.getElementsByName("Icon").value;
            var title = document.getElementById("Title").value;
            var description = document.getElementById("Description").value;
            var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
            var icon = new OpenLayers.Icon(iconT);
            var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(position);
            var lonlatTransf = lonlat.transform(map.getProjectionObject(), proj4326);
            var longitude = lonlatTransf.lon;
            var latitude = lonlatTransf.lat;

            var lonlat = lonlatTransf.transform(proj4326, map.getProjectionObject());
            /*var markerslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");*/


            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: { 'desc': description, 'title': title, 'icon': iconT, 'lon': longitude, 'lat': latitude },
                url: '@Url.Action("Test")',
                success: function () {
                    alert('Your Marker was saved successfully!');
                    addMarker(title, description, longitude, latitude);
                    /* markerslayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat, icon));
                    map.addLayer(markerslayer);*/
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert(thrownError.toString());
                }
            });

        });
        /*map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());*/
    }

    function addMarker(title,description,lon,lat){
        var markerslayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
        map.addLayer(markerLayer);

        lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat);
        marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonLat);
        markerLayer.addMarker(marker);
        marker.icon.imageDiv.title = title; //is this correct way to add title? How can I description too?
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your map variable is local to your init function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function init() {
    var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
```

Remove the "var":

```
var map;
function init() {
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I totally forgot about that and did not see the bug thanks for pointing it out!
Can you help me setting the lon and lat too please cause the wrong lon and lat are being set for some reason

Comment: That is probably a different question and requires more information, please create one with at least the following: 1. what do you mean by "the wrong lon and lat are being set"?  2. What are you seeing?  3. What do you expect to see? 4. a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem (or a link to a page that does; in addition to the code you are using)?